# How to change a variable UITextView after clicking the button?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I create `UITextView` with a random tag and text, but it is created with one variable, is it possible to update the variable after creation `UITextView` (by clicking the add button)? Maybe add a random number to it, for example newText1, newText2.. etc.

So that the next `UITextView` is already created with a new variable?

*P.S Sorry, if the question is silly, I just recently started to study Swift*

```
@IBOutlet weak var addTextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var StoriesView: UIView!

var newText = UITextView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func addTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let maxNumber = 10000
        let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber)))

        newText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: self.StoriesView.frame.origin.x + 40, y: self.StoriesView.frame.origin.y + 40, width: 380, height: 80))
         self.StoriesView.addSubview(newText)

         newText.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 11)
         newText.text = "TAP TO EDIT #\(i)"
         newText.sizeToFit()
         newText.textColor = UIColor.black
         newText.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
         newText.tag = i

         newText.isEditable = true
         newText.isSelectable = true
         newText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         newText.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
         newText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

         newText.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true

         newText.delegate = self       
       }
```

UPD:

```
let fontToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        fontToolbar.barStyle = .default
        fontToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Green", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(greenColor)),
             UIBarButtonItem(title: "Blue", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(blueColor)),
             UIBarButtonItem(title: "Red", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(redColor)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close Keyboard", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))]
        fontToolbar.sizeToFit()
        newText.inputAccessoryView = fontToolbar
```

in the toolBar above the keyboard I have buttons, here we change the color

```
@objc func redColor() {
        newText.textColor = UIColor.red}

    @objc func blueColor() {
        newText.textColor = UIColor.blue}

    @objc func greenColor() {
        newText.textColor = UIColor.green}
```

So the color changes only in the newly created `UITextView`

Comment: Yes, have you tried this? Did it give you any error?

Comment: Of course, you can create a new instance of `UITextView` and assign it to `newText` variable. But if you need to change text, just assign a new string to `newText.text` property.

Comment: @Rob It works with such code, new `UITextView` are created, but then I need to open the keyboard so that certain functions work and they only work with the newly created `UITextView`, but not with the previous one

Comment: @Dmitry you are overriding `newText` value everytime. So the newest textfield added is actually `newText`.

Comment: @KeshuR. Yes, and I don’t know how to fix it...

Comment: @Dmitry: What is frame of your StoriesView view?

Comment: @AlexSmet I thought that it would be enough to change the tag so that the object was considered new, but because of the same variable every time it was created, it works normally only with new UITextView

Comment: @RJ168 In the future, all objects inside `StoriesView` will be saved as a screenshot

Comment: @Dmitry How you use `newText` variable in your program?

Comment: @AlexSmet I plan to make a toolBar, when `newText` and keyboard are active,then I could change the font, size and color of the `newText` and these functions are attached to the variable

Comment: @Dmitry Added a solution to match your requirement. Please validate and let me know is it as per you exceptions or not.

Comment: @RJ168 UITextView is already created, and I can move it around the screen, but I need it so that I can change the color and font, but it changes it in a variable and does it only in every new UITextView

Comment: @RJ168 change only last UITextView (number 10) https://imgur.com/wT24PIr

Comment: @Dmitry Updated the code to add and access all the TextView elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click of button, create a new texView and assign it a tag value. Once it is added, update the value of i to +1, so that every textView added has a new tag value.

```
var i = 1
var newText = UITextView()

@IBAction func addTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

    newText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: self.StoriesView.frame.origin.x + 40, y: self.StoriesView.frame.origin.y + 40, width: 380, height: 80))
     self.StoriesView.addSubview(newText)

    newText.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 11)
    newText.text = "TAP TO EDIT #\(i)"
    newText.sizeToFit()
    newText.textColor = UIColor.black
    newText.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    newText.tag = i

    newText.isEditable = true
    newText.isSelectable = true
    newText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newText.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    newText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    newText.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true

    newText.delegate = self
    //increment i
    i+=1
}
```

then you can access your textField via tag values like this:

```
if let textView = self.StoriesView.viewWithTag(i) as? UITextView {
     // textView.text = "change it"   
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Add textView Delegate method, and once a textView starts editing, change the newText value to the currently editing textView

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        newText = textView
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is how tags are set in 1, 2, 3..., but when I call the keyboard, I have a button there that works only with new `UITextView`, but if I call the previous one `UITextView`, the keyboard opens, but the button no longer performs the function

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit to have new `UITextView` object with button click

```
import UIKit

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var StoriesView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var addTextButton: UIButton!
  var yposition: CGFloat!
  var textFieldTag: [Int]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yposition = 20
  }

  @IBAction func addTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let xposition = self.StoriesView.frame.origin.x
    let maxNumber = 10000
    let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber)))
    textFieldTag.append(i)

    let newText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: xposition , y: yposition , width: 380, height: 40))
    self.StoriesView.addSubview(newText)

    newText.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 11)
    newText.text = "TAP TO EDIT #\(i)"
    newText.sizeToFit()
    newText.textColor = UIColor.black
    newText.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    newText.tag = i

    newText.isEditable = true
    newText.isSelectable = true
    newText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newText.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    newText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    newText.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
    newText.delegate = self

    yposition = yposition + 45
  }

  @IBAction func accessTextFields(_ sender: Any) {

    //access all text fields
    for tag in textFieldTag {
      if let textField = self.StoriesView.viewWithTag(tag) as? UITextView {
        //change properties here
        textField.backgroundColor = .cyan
      }
    }

    //access specific text fields
    if let textField = self.StoriesView.viewWithTag(textFieldTag.first!) as? UITextView {
      //change properties here
      textField.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    if let textField = self.StoriesView.viewWithTag(textFieldTag[textFieldTag.count - 1]) as? UITextView {
      //change properties here
      textField.backgroundColor = .green
    }
  }
}
```

It will have an output as this!!

> [image]

Comment: Here in `textFieldTag` you can find all the tags and can access `UITextView ` elements according to it anytime.